# How to create a templated function taking a variable number of arguments that passes the arguments to an object's correct constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, lua, c++11, variadic

I have the following templated function...

```
template< class T > T *create_object( lua_State *L )    
{
    // Get a raw block of memory, managed by Lua.
    void *mem = lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( T ) );
    // Construct the object in the allocated memory.
    T *object = new (mem) T;
    // Do other stuff here...
    return object;
}
```

... that allocates and sets up a C++ object for use in the Lua scripting language. I'd like to extend this function so I can pass in arguments for the object's constructor. It might look something like this:

```
template< class T > T *create_object( lua_State *L, ??? ctor_args )    
{
    void *mem = lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( T ) );
    T *object = new (mem) T( ctor_args ); // Call correct constructor as determined by args.
    // ...
    return object;
}
```

... and work something like this:

```
class widget
{
    public:
        // Multiple constructors
        widget(); // #1
        widget( const widget &w ); // #2
        widget( int width, int height, float x, float y ); //#3
};

class font
{
    public:
        font( std::vector<uint8_t> );
}

// Other classes with multiple constructors.

// Example usage: (L = lua_State pointer)
create_object<widget>( L ); // Pass no arguments - use constructor #1
create_object<widget>( L, existing_widget ); // Pass one argument- use constructor #2
create_object<widget>( L, 128, 64, 100.0f, 100.0f ); // Pass 4 arguments - use construct #3
create_object<font>( L, buffer ); // Just to show it needs to work with many object types...
... and so on ...
```

Avoiding a variadic template that ends up like this:

```
create_object<widget, int, int, float, float >( L, 256, 512, 120.0f, 0.0f );
```

Would be nice.

Is this possible in c++11?

Update: I'm currently using gcc 4.6 with -pedantic turned on. Non compiler-specific solutions would be preferred.

Comment: If `lua_newuserdata` doesn't guarantee alignment for any object size (I don't know whether it does or not), then you'll need to do that yourself -- `sizeof(T)` is not sufficient.

Comment: @idjarn I think the Lua API isn't well enough specified on this issue. I think the memory will be aligned but they don't explicitly say it. I'd just stick in a line: `assert(reinterpret_cast<intmax_t>(mem) % alignof(T) == 0)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this, provided you have proper support for variadic templates:

```
template< class T, typename... Args > 
T *create_object( lua_State *L, Args&&... args)    
{
    void *mem = lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( T ) );
    T *object = new (mem) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // ...
    return object;
}
```

This will correctly forward references, even your constructor takes some of its arguments by (const or not) reference and other by value.